# Extracting Identity from lambda authorizer response

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-net, lambda-authorizer

I made a custom lambda authorizer that validates the JWT and returns `Allow` policy.

```
 var context = new APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerContextOutput();

 var tokenUse = ExtractClaims(claims, "token_use");
 context["tokenType"] = tokenUse;
 var response = new APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerResponse
 {
     PrincipalID = "asd",
     PolicyDocument = new APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerPolicy
     {
         Version = "2012-10-17",
         Statement = new List<APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerPolicy.IAMPolicyStatement>()
         {
             new APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerPolicy.IAMPolicyStatement
             {
                 Action = new HashSet<string>() {"execute-api:Invoke"},
                 Effect = "Allow",
                 Resource = new HashSet<string>() {"***"} // resource arn here
              }
          },
      },
      Context = context
 };

 return response;
```

Now I need to use this Identity on my resource server.

The problem is that the claims I put in the authorizer context appears under `authorizer` directly

```
 "authorizer": {
            "cognito:groups": "Admin", ...
 }
```

but my `Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction` expects those under `authorizer.claims`.

like such:

```
 "authorizer": {
            "claims": {
                "cognito:groups": "Admin", ... 
             }
  }
```

And I know that, because it was working when I was using the built in Cognito User Pool authorizer, which was making the input like that.

I managed to find that Lambda Authorizer is not allowed to add nested objects to the context (and tested that it throws `authorizer error` if I do.)

I also found that when `APIGatewayProxyFunction` is extracting the Identity, it looks at Authorizer.Claims.

So I need to either extract them on my resource server bypassing the `Claims` property somehow, or add a nested object to the authorizer response, which is not allowed.

What do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I solved this by overriding the `PostCreateContext` method on my `LambdaEntryPoint : Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction`.

```
protected override void PostCreateContext(
        HostingApplication.Context context,
        APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayRequest, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
{
        // handling output from cognito user pool authorizer
        if (apiGatewayRequest?.RequestContext?.Authorizer?.Claims != null)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(apiGatewayRequest.RequestContext.Authorizer.Claims.Select(
                entry => new Claim(entry.Key, entry.Value.ToString())), "AuthorizerIdentity");

            context.HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            return;
        }

        // handling output from lambda authorizer
        if (apiGatewayRequest?.RequestContext?.Authorizer != null)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(apiGatewayRequest.RequestContext.Authorizer.Select(
                entry => new Claim(entry.Key, entry.Value.ToString())), "AuthorizerIdentity");

            context.HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        }
    }
```

Edit: also submitted a pull reqeust to the aws-lambda-dotnet library fixing this.

Edit 2: My pull request has been merged for some time and this is not an issue anymore if using an up to date `Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer` (not sure which version first had it, but 3.1.0 definitely has it)